# Jest: How to utilize its features in unit testing an application

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, enzyme, jestjs

I am new to jest and unit-testing as well, and I'm wondering what type of scenarios can be covered using Jest.

I have some specific questions before I get started:

- What should be covered in unit-testing the react application?
- Do I need any other library with Jest for assertions, mocking etc? I read about Chai, sinon etc. Not aware why they are used and if they are needed with Jest.
- What exactly is Enzyme used for? Is it a must-use with Jest?
- Do I need any task-runner with Jest like Karma? Or does Jest have one built-in? How do I set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should be covered in unit-testing the react application?

Nobody can answer this for you. As a rough plan, think about the consequences of different functionality breaking. Start with the most problematic scenarios, and work your way down. At some point, you'll find a balance between effort of writing tests and those consequences of things breaking, and stop. Where this is depends entirely on your application.

> Do I need any other library with Jest for assertions, mocking etc? I read about Chai, sinon etc. Not aware why they are used and are they needed with Jest.

Jest has [assertions](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html) out of the box, as it's built on Jasmine. This should meet your needs, and should be used unless you have a *very* specific reason to use an alternative such as chai.

Sinon is something different entirely - it's a spy framework used to inspect how functions are called - you might use assertions on the results of these inspections. As far as I know Jest does not have anything similar built in (at time of writing, this might change or have already changed), so if you need this, you should use it.

> What exactly is Enzyme used for? Is it a must-use with Jest?

Enzyme is a utility library for mocking renders and other interactions on real React components, and then running assertions on their output. I would strongly recommend using it to test React components, specifically. It's not a must-use with Jest in general, as Jest can be used to write tests for anything, not just React components.

> Do I need any task-runner with Jest like Karma? Or Jest has one built-in? How do I set it up.

No. Jest *is* a test runner.

Comment: @Manu glad I could help!